# filling screen with rotating linear-gradient background

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have created a rotating linear-gradient background. Unfortunately, as it rotates, in the corners you can see white screen. I am trying to get it so the color fills the viewport with nothing visible but the rotating gradient.

Here is my code so far (done on codepen.io):

HTML

```
<div class="fade"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.fade {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue, red);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  animation: revolve 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes revolve {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

I originally had the scale3d as (2,2,1). Changing it to (1,1,1) didn't solve anything. I have also tried changing the height and width to greater than 100wv and setting a background-position of center center, but neither of those worked.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/mdrJYgx?editors=1100).

Answer (score -1):

Use the `vmax` unit like below to create a big overflowing square:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.fade {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue, red);
  position:absolute;
  height: 200vmax;
  width: 200vmax;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  animation: revolve 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes revolve {
  to {
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fade"></div>
```

You can simplify with a pseudo element:

```css
html::before {
  content:"";
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue, red);
  position:fixed;
  top:-50vmax;
  bottom:-50vmax;
  left:-50vmax;
  right:-50vmax;
  animation: revolve 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes revolve {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```